# Какой шаблон (портфолио,интернет-маг...) могут подойти для сайта с личным кабинетом

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны, localstorage, site

Стоит задача, создать сайт с личным кабинетом. На самом сайте будет игра 
"Викторина".
Какой шаблон посоветовали бы использовать или лучше делать сайт с нуля ? 
Есть ли такие подходящие шаблоны на WP или нет ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У WordPress нет на "фронте" личного кабинета, поэтому, Вам нужно начинать не с шаблонов, а с плагина, который Вам будет этот личный кабинет предоставлять. 
Поищите сначала плагин с личным кабинетом на "фронте" ( магазин или продажу подписок ), а потом уже шаблон ( тему ) которая поддерживает этот плагин.